# Проверка всей строки массива на нахождение элементов

Tags: c, массивы

Дана следующая задача:
Дана целочисленная квадратная матрица А порядка N, где N — заданное натуральное число. Если в матрице А есть строка, все элементы которой являются удвоенными нечетными числами, то вывести на экран сообщение «Да», иначе сообщение «Нет».

Вот код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Math.h>
#include <locale.h>
#define size 100
int main(void) {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    int i,j,n;
    int array[size][size];
    int x,y=0;
    printf("Введите порядок n: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            printf("Введите %d элемент массива: ",++x);
            scanf("%d",&array[i][j]);
            if (array[i][j]%2==0 && array[i][j]%4 != 0)
            {
                y++;
            }
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for ( j = 0; j < n; j++ )
        {
            printf( "%d \t", array[i][j] );
        }
        printf( "\n" );
    }
    if(y>0)
    {
        printf("Да");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Нет");
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

В моём коде, работает так, что если хотя бы один элемент во всей матрице соответствует условию задачи, то мне выводит "Да". Проблема в том, что я не знаю, как проверить всю строку, а не один элемент.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот решение "в лоб" с двумя булевыми переменными:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Math.h>
#include <locale.h>
#define size 100
int main(void) {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    int i, j, n;
    int array[size][size];
    int x = 0,  // x тоже обязательно нужно инициализировать, иначе ++x вернёт неизвестно что
        y = 0;
    printf("Введите порядок n: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    bool stringFound = false;   // Переменная, показывающая, надена ли нужная строка

    for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        bool elementFound = true;   // Переменная, показывающая, что очередное число подряд удовлетворяет условию
        for (j = 0; j<n; j++)
        {
            printf("Введите %d элемент массива: ", ++x);
            scanf("%d", &array[i][j]);
            if (!(array[i][j] % 2 == 0 && array[i][j] % 4 != 0))    // Если вдруг одно из чисел в строке не удовлетворяет условию
            {
                elementFound = false;   // Значит эта строка не подходит
            }
        }
        if (elementFound)
            stringFound = true;         // Если после прохождения всей строки переменная осталась true, значит все числа удовлетворяли условию, 
                                        // а значит нужная строка найдена.
    }
    for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            printf("%d \t", array[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    if (stringFound)
    {
        printf("Да");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Нет");
    }

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Прочитайте мои комментарии к коду, из них должна быть понятна логика. Также я поясню здесь, как рассуждал. Итак, Вы перебираете элементы каждой строки в цикле со счётчиком `j` (а цикл со счётчиком `i` перебирает сами строки). Я решил, что стоит пойти от обратного. То есть заранее принять, что элементы данной строки удовлетворяют условию и только потом, если так не окажется, менять переменную, отвечающую за это. Суть в том, что при проходе по строке мы проверяем каждый элемент на удовлетворение условия и если оно не выполняется, вся строка признаётся не удовлетворяющей условию. Если же каждый элемент строки удовлетворял условию, то переменная, отвечающая за это (`elementFound`), так и не будет изменена, и тогда мы можем считать, что нужная строка найдена: `stringFound = true;`.

P.S. Также прошу Вас обратить внимание на мой комментарий по поводу инициализации `x`, т.к. без этого изначально в данной переменной будет находиться неопределённое значение. И ещё вызывает сомнения, что Вы объявляете массив фиксированного размера, какое бы `n` не ввели. В таком случае, если будет введено `n < size`, Вы потратите лишнюю память, а если `n > size`, то вообще выйдете за границы массива и программа упадёт. Пользуйтесь лучше динамическим массивом и объявляйте его размером `n` на `n`, а не больше или меньше.

P.P.S. Моё решение данной задачи не претендует на элегантность. Я уверен, что можно решить её более коротко и изящно, но, к сожалению, у меня нет времени как следует над этим поразмыслить.

Comment: Большое спасибо